# Why applied Font is removed upon font.dispose() in swt?

Tags: java, swt, eclipse-rcp

I have created an SWT Table and added columns to it. I want to apply bold font to header row alone. So my code looks like below

```
 Table table= new Table(top, tableStyle);  
 Font font = new Font(null, StringUtils.EMPTY, 9, SWT.BOLD);
 for (int i = 0; i < titles.length; i++) 
 {
        new TableColumn(table, SWT.NONE);
        header.setFont(i, font);
        header.setText(i, titles[i]);
 }
 font.dispose();
```

In the above code, I have disposed as it is a good practice to do. But this is removing the font style from the header. If I remove the last line, font remains applied.

Is there any mistake over here? Or is this the expected behavior?

Comment: SWT needs to use the font the entire time the table is displayed. It is only safe to dispose of it when the table is disposed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to wait and only `dispose()` the `Font` when you no longer need it. You could tie the disposal to the dispose event of the table so you don't have to manually dispose it:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    final Display d = new Display();
    Shell s = new Shell(d);
    s.setLayout(new FillLayout());

    Table table = new Table(s, SWT.NONE);
    Font font = new Font(null, "", 12, SWT.BOLD);
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        TableItem item = new TableItem(table, SWT.NONE);
        item.setFont(font);
        item.setText("" + i);
    }

    table.addListener(SWT.Dispose, e -> font.dispose());

    s.pack();
    s.open();

    while (!s.isDisposed())
    {
        if (!d.readAndDispatch())
            d.sleep();
    }
    d.dispose();
}
```

Comment: The `!font.isDisposed()` check is not needed. Calling `dispose()` on an already disposed of font in SWT is legal.